# Syntax error in MATLAB recurrence equation

Tags: matlab, mupad

I have looked up [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/rec.html) how to declare recurrence equations.

I tried the following example from that page:

```
>> solve(rec(y(n + 1) = 3*(n + 1)*y(n), y(n), {y(0) = 1}))
                      |
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

Then I noticed that I didn't have the `Symbolic Math Toolbox` installed. After the installation

```
>> ver
```

returned (among some others):

```
MATLAB                                                Version 8.1        (R2013a)
Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 5.10       (R2013a)
```

but I still got the above error.

I could narrow the command down to the following, giving the same above error:

```
>> rec(y(n + 1) = y(n), y(n), {y(0) = 1})
                |
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

On the wiki and other google results, the error is only mentioned with a error when confusing `=` with `==`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`rec`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/rec.html) is not a native Symbolic Toolbox function. It belongs to MuPAD which is a separate package that [Mathworks acquired and added to Symbolic Toolbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MuPAD). To use it you need to first enter `mupad` command in command window then you enter the command that uses `rec` in MuPAD window that pops up.

Comment: You can also evaluate MuPAD expressions from within MATLAB using `evalin(symengine, '...')`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/evalin.html